# Cloning textures without causing duplicate card memory in THREE.js

Tags: three.js

I am using sprite sheets to create animated textures with THREE.js. Each sprite instance utilizes texture offsets to control which of the images to present that frame. Multiple animated sprites may be on the screen at once.

Currently I am using Texture.clone() to duplicate the sprite sheet texture. However, unless I set *Texture.needsUpdate* to true, the texture will not display on the sprites. Setting *needsUpdate* to true allows me to display multiple independent animated sprites at once, but unfortunately this causes the texture memory to be duplicate on the card (/ integrated chip). Using Chrome WebGL Inspector I can clearly see that the sprite texture has been duplicate the same number of times as animated sprites that have been rendered.

Is there any way to clone / reuse the texture with different offsets for each instance without duplicating the memory? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong.

THREE.js r67

**Update**:

One way that we have gotten around this (not a great way I admit) is to duplicate the GL texture ID assigned to the original texture and set the cloned texture as being initialized.

```
clonedTexture.__webglTexture = origTexture.__webglTexture;
clonedTexture.__webglInit = true;
```

This requires that the texture has already been sent to the card, which we force with render.setTexture(origTexture...).

Comment: It appears you are doing what was intended -- by cloning, the textures share the image. Does `renderer.info.memory` confirm your suspicion?

Comment: @WestLangley, yes, I can confirm that indeed the textures have been duplicated, and confirms what WGL inspector also says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that's in the works. Keep an eye for whenever `THREE.Image` lands.